# Chromium OS build image ：mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/host/source/src/build’: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, chroot, google-chrome-os, chromium-os

When I follow the Chromium OS Developer Guide and run:./build_image --board=${BOARD} --noenable_rootfs_verification dev I meet

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/host/source/src/build’: Permission  denied
ERROR   : 2016year 11month 27day Sunday 13:10:03 CST
ERROR   :  PGID  PPID   PID     ELAPSED     TIME %CPU COMMAND
ERROR   :    12     6    12    01:29:43 00:00:00  0.0 -bash
ERROR   : 14953    12 14953       00:08 00:00:00  1.1  \_ /bin/bash ./build_image --board=x86-generic --noenable_rootfs_verification dev
ERROR   : 14953 14953 15284       00:00 00:00:00  0.0      \_ /bin/bash ./build_image --board=x86-generic --noenable_rootfs_verification dev
ERROR   : 14953 15284 15285       00:00 00:00:00  0.0          \_ ps f -o pgid,ppid,pid,etime,cputime,%cpu,command
ERROR   : Arguments of 14953: ./build_image '--board=x86-generic' '--noenable_rootfs_verification' 'dev'
ERROR   : Backtrace:  (most recent call is last)
ERROR   :  build_image:181:main(), called: die_err_trap  
ERROR   : 
ERROR   : Command failed:
ERROR   :   Command 'mkdir -p "${BUILD_DIR}"' exited with nonzero code: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read this [Chromium Doc](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/tips-and-tricks-for-chromium-os-developers#TOC-Making-sudo-a-little-more-permissive)

While you are at it please [Verify that your default file permissions (umask) setting is correct](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-guide#TOC-Verify-that-your-default-file-permissions-umask-setting-is-correct)

Answer (score -4):

Use sodu can solve this problem

Comment: no, don't use sudo at all when building Chromium OS.  it will only screw things up more.